# Using bar graph to present a data from csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, visualization

Suppose I have this csv file:

```
CODE     AGE GROUP     SEX     CITY      
----     ---------     ---     ----      
E101      25 to 29      M      Denver     
E102      25 to 29      F      Denver       
E105      25 to 29      M      Denver
```

I wish to present it using a bar graph but I'm not sure how to count the number of males and females in it.  This is what I've coded so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('bmh')

x = df['SEX']
y = # what should I put here?

plt.xlabel('Sex', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Number of people', fontsize=16)
plt.bar(x, y)
```

What should I put in "y" for it to count the number of males and females in the data?

Comment: @Mr.T yes I'm using pandas.  How can I utilize it in grouping and counting the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the dataframe plot method like this:
df["SEX"].value_counts().plot(kind="bar")

Otherwise, plt.bar() is expecting a list as long as the number of groups (0, 1) for x and the associated counts (2, 1) for y. It’s a bit harder to make sure the labels and counts align this way so I suggest the dataframe method. Your solution does not provide the correct value for x.

Comment: `It’s a bit harder to make sure the labels and counts align` -- i don't agree. `df.value_counts()` returns two columns with the same length, so one can be x and the other can be y.

Comment: Usually I’d agree, but extracting the labels when setting xlabel can be a problem. Extracting keys and values in the same order is not guaranteed from a dictionary, and getting them out in the right order is a pain mostly. The method still works - it just takes more code, which is more difficult and harder to read.